# How do I dynamically add url,userid and password from my properties file to Hibernate config.xml?

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, properties-file

I have a database.properties file(that contains url, password, username) for each environment(test,prod,dev) and they have to be changed dynamically when I am pointing to a particular environment. How do I add them in my Hibernate-config.xml. Currently, I have manually added them as a workaround.

Thanks,
Gautham

Comment: Are you using Maven to build your application?

Comment: Yes, maven, spring and hibernate

Comment: Ok, what you can do is create profile variables, for each environment, and replace them on your *hibernate-config.xml*, using the Maven filtering capacity.